# Difference between USB CDC EEM protocol implementations in Win10 (usbnet.sys) and Linux kernel (cdc_eem.c)

Tags: linux, windows, usb, ethernet, cdc

My USB CDC-EEM device works well together with a host running Raspberry Pi OS (Debian). But when I try to connect this device to a PC running Microsoft Windows 10, the communication fails, even if the USB device gets configured well and starts operation.

First difference here: the Windows EEM driver will stop if the USB device does not correctly respond to SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE (0x22) CDC class request, which is not required by the Linux driver to start up.

But even after Windows driver started successfully and brings up a virtual NIC, the communication of Ethernet frames seems broken.

Capturing the BULK OUT traffic (packets sent from Win10 to my device), we can see for example the following USB transfer:

```
0000   00 52 33 33 f0 24 8c 11 76 50 47 a3 29 28 86 dd   .R33....vP...(..
0010   60 00 00 00 00 18 3a ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   `.....:.........
0020   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0030   00 00 00 01 ff 04 9c 01 87 00 f9 d8 00 00 00 00   ................
0040   fe 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 4c dd a0 65 5d 04 9c 01   ........L..e]...
0050   de ad be ef                                       ....
```

Important are the first 2 bytes (0x00, 0x52), which should contain a valid EEM Data Packet header, as specified by CDC EEM Spec Rev 1.0, chapter 5.1.2.1. It seems that the Windows driver uses a different endianness. Actually big endian (BE), while the Linux kernel driver uses little endian (LE), as it can be read here:

```c
/* EEM packet header format:
 * b0..13:  length of ethernet frame
 * b14:     bmCRC (1 == valid Ethernet CRC)
 * b15:     bmType (0 == data)
 */
len = skb->len;
put_unaligned_le16(BIT(14) | len, skb_push(skb, 2));
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a180bd1d7e16173d965b263c5a536aa40afa2a2a/drivers/net/usb/cdc_eem.c#L139

Seems like Microsofts developers decided to use BE, since this is also used by the Ethernet frame payload. E.g. the CRC sentinal value (0xDEADBEEF) is also stored using BE. But this is part of the Ethernet standard and not CDC-EEM nor USB. The CDC-EEM spec is not very strict, but I interpret it to use LE: CDC-EEM spec chapter 5.1.1 refers to [USB2.0] 8.4. The USB spec defines to use Little Endian (LE) as the default, as can be read inside chapter 8.1:

```
Multiple byte fields in standard descriptors, requests, and responses are interpreted as and moved over the
bus in little-endian order, i.e., LSB to MSB.
```

Now I am not sure if...

- this is a bug of the Windows driver, not correctly following the CDC-EEM spec?
- there is an easy way to change the Windows driver endianness?
- there is an acceptable solution to detect the endianness of the host driver?

If it is possible to wait for a first Ethernet frame received from the host, then it should be an easy job to detect the endianness from the first 2 bytes. I assume there are only few cases that will be ambiguous. But as a result, it is not possible to transfer any Ethernet frames to the host before the successful detection of endianness. Or it is also feasible to use "Host identification using USB Fingerprinting" (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6159115) and change endianness depending on host OS. But all these solutions have the smell of some dirty workaround.

Finally it is very hard to believe that Microsoft didn't validated their driver somehow. Maybe there are some USB EEM devices available that actually work with BE endianness?

My Windows OS shows the following driver details:

```
Generic USB-EEM Network Adapter

Driver files: C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\usbnet.sys

Provider: Microsoft Corporation
File version: 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
```

Comment: Have you captured the USB traffic to some other CDC Ethernet device?  Perhaps Windows is activating some compatibility shim because (to it) your device responds like some buggy device.

Comment: @BenVoigt: good suggestion. Unfortunately I have no other USB EEM device that I can use for comparison. Hopefully, somebody who owns such a device can spend some minutes to hook it up to Windows 10 and capture an USB trace, e.g. using Wireshark.